# Comparison with 0 or 1, to detect high impedence

Tags: vhdl

I know that its not allowed to compare with `X` or `Z` in a synthesizable VHDL code. But is it allowed to write a code in which I compare a signal to `0` or `1` to detect an `Z` and suspend the operation? The code is as follows:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk ) then
    if(rst = '0') then
      reg_0 <= (others => 'Z');
    elsif(btf_start = '1') then
      reg_0 <= "ZZ" & frame_in;
    elsif(t_btf_finish = '1') then
      reg_0 <= (others => 'Z');
    end if;
  end if;  
end process;

process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if(reg_0(0) = '0' or reg_0(0) = '1') then
        -- DO SOME OPERATIONS
    else
        -- DO NOTHING
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this won't work. Physical digital signals can have exactly 2 states, '0' and '1'. The states are defined by the voltage on the signal: less than some voltage is a '0', greater than that voltage is a '1'. Even floating (high-z) signals will have some voltage that will be interpreted as a '1' or '0'.

'Z' basically says that a certain source isn't driving the signal, allowing a different source to drive a '0' or '1'. For the case when no source is driving the signal, the signal will usually have a pull-up or pull-down resistor to keep it in a defined '1' or '0' state by default.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. The explanation makes sense.  I was confused because I used similar code in one of my modules and it worked both in pre synthesis(modelsim) and post synthesis simultions(ise). But when I implemented the whole design in fpga it didn't work as expected. Normally the post synthesis simulation should detect all these faults right?

Comment: @dmm Ideally it should, but it depends strongly on how the vendor implemented the simulation libraries for their primitives. Apparently in your case the simulation libraries didn't exactly model the physical behavior. Honestly, for this and similar reasons, I consider post synthesis simulations a waste of time; using a logic analyzer such as Chipscope or Signal Tap in an FPGA prototype is usually a much faster and more realistic option.